# Busca em jQuery exibindo a TR mais proxima como cabeçalho!

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CONSEGUI A RESPOSTA NO STACK AMERICANO, SEGUE LINK DA RESPOSTA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46654887/588842**

Tenho o seguinte `HTML` e `JS`:

SEGUE LINK DO FIDDLE EXTERNO: https://jsfiddle.net/qpouvped/

```js
$(".filter-nome").keyup(function(){

  var valor = $(this).val();
  $(".lista-certidoes tbody tr").each(function(index){

    $row = $(this);
    var id = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    if (id.indexOf(valor) != 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
<label for="nome">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-nome" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
<label for="oab">Nº</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-oab" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
<label for="protocolo">Nº Protocolo</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-protocolo" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered lista-certidoes">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Nº</th>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Nº PROTOCOLO</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="3" class="cab_interno">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >137418</td>
       <td >Nonono Nonono Nonono</td>
       <td >11225566</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="3" class="cab_interno">B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >122222</td>
       <td >Nonono Nonono Nonono</td>
       <td >11225566</td>
      </tr>
      ...
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Até ai tudo bem, funcionando normal, porém, gostaria de deixar exibindo a TR que tem a td com a classe `.cab_interno`, que é a Letra correspondente à aquela "parte" da lista.

Tentei utilizar isso abaixo, junto com o `$(this).show();`, mas não funcionou..

```
$(this).closest('tr > td.cab_interno').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    console.log("OK");
});
```

Alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda ai ?

Comment: No seu html não encontrei onde está a classe "filter-nome" poderia editar a pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei, é um input simples, coloquei também um link com o Fiddle externo

Answer (score 0):

Separei a tabela em vários `<tbody>` para agrupar os dados.

Após a pesquisa no `input` será exibido somente o `tbody` que possuir em algumas das suas linhas um nome igual ao valor digitado no `input`.

Vale lembrar que o `Javascript` diferencia maiúsculas de minusculas.

```js
$(".filter-nome").keyup(function(){

  var valor = $(this).val();
  $(".cab_interno tr").each(function(index){
    
    //Tbody atual:
    $cabecalho  = $(this).parent("tbody"); 
    
    //linha do tbody:
    $linha      = $(this); 
    
    //Coluna nome:
    $nome       = $linha.find("td:nth-child(2)").text(); 

    if ($nome.indexOf(valor) != 0) {
      //$cabecalho.hide();
      $linha.hide();
      
    }
    else {
      $linha.show();
      $cabecalho.find("tr:first-child").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cab_interno th{
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
<label for="nome">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-nome" value="">
  </div>
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered lista-certidoes">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Nº</th>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Nº PROTOCOLO</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody class="cab_interno">
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3">A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>137418</td>
       <td>Texto A</td>
       <td>11225566</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody class="cab_interno">
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>122222</td>
       <td>Texto 1B</td>
       <td>11225566</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>122222</td>
       <td>Texto 2B</td>
       <td>11225566</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
      <tbody class="cab_interno">
         <tr>
            <th colspan="3">C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>122222</td>
            <td>Nononono</td>
            <td>11225566</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>133</td>
            <td>Nanana Nonono Nonono</td>
            <td>11225566</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Funcionou não.. se eu procuro por Texto B, ele não acha nada... Eu quero pesquisar por nome da pessoa, e exibir também a Letra Alfabetica correspondente. Do jeito que você fez, só exibe se eu buscar a letra B do "cabecalho"

Comment: Cara, olha esse Fiddle, copiei seu código, e não está funcionando. Onde que estou errando? O seu aqui funcionou certinho... https://jsfiddle.net/qpouvped/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpouvped/1/

Comment: Entendi, é uma lista grande, com vários nomes dentro de cada letra... mas vlws a ajuda.. vou tentar algo aqui...

Comment: Alterei o código agrupando por <tbody> e buscando em todas suas linhas,  dessa forma quando umas das linhas conter o nome digitado somente esse tbody será exibido. Veja se o resultado é o desejado.

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou, mas eu precisava que fosse exibido somente a pessoa buscada, e não todo <tbody>. Eu pedi ajuda no StackOverflow em ingles, colocaram uma resposta lá! Vou deixar ela aqui no post! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e tempo Caique..

Comment: Pode deixar ai, é uma outra forma de exibição...

Comment: Agora acho que foi, testei com diversas linhas dentro e estava ok